# angular - directive scopes not destroyed

Tags: angularjs, compilation, scope, angular-directive

I have a very strange problem with AngularJS & Compile functionality:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7W9AbpaLqsYCecOWdIlz?p=preview

I wrote a simple $compile structure, so I can insert dynamically different html-templates.

If you've a look into the BodyController you'll the in the "INIT"-Event, I'm changing my states and show UI's.

```
uiService.changeState("LOGIN");
uiService.showUI("LOGIN_VIEW"); 
uiService.changeState("GAME");
//Change state - show test one,
uiService.showUI("TEST1_VIEW");
```

After I skipped back to login and changed back to GAME, he's showing "Test1" three times, aswell as "Test2" one time, but just "Test1" should shown one time.

Also the pre-compile directive isn't destroyed an executed.

I'm firing the scope().$destroy event each time, but seems like the core doesn't realize this rightly?

Hopefully somone can help me.
Thanks

Edit: 
Crosslink: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9190

Update:
Found the issue, but don't know how to solve:

After compiling:

```
angularScope = angular.element(document).scope();
$compile(controlEle)(angularScope);
```

angularScope ($rootScope) adds a listener onto:

```
$stateChangeSuccess
```

This $stateChangeSuccess-Listener isn't cleared on

```
$state.go
```

If I clear it myself, the bug is gone - but the shouldn't be the right case?

```
angularScope.$$listeners.$stateChangeSuccess = [];
angularScope.$$listeners.$viewContentLoading = [];
```

Seems like the $destroy-event of the child-scopes doesn't effect the listener on the $rootScope.